# How do I use Supabases's new GraphQL function with Sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, graphql-js, supabase

I was excited to hear that Supabase recently added the ability to query with GraphQL, but the documentation is sparse to say the least.

What would be the steps to using GraphQL with Supabase in Sveltekit? From the Next.js demo app (https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-graphql-example) it looks like I'd need to pull in `graphql` and maybe `urql` but otherwise I'm not sure of the process. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you end up building this? i'd be interested in code examples

Comment: @FinnLucaFrotscher yes, I discovered a package called Houdini GraphQL that makes it very simple: https://houdinigraphql.com/